# Configuring PDO drivers for MySQL on Windows for PHP 5.6.3

Tags: php, pdo

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\debug\pdo.PHP on line 13

Anyone here knows how to solve this? I've uncommented the PDO extension but still persists and @ other time is get

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\pdo_oop\pdo_fetch.php on line 52

It's a different script but the same code pattern was used. I'm running PHP 5.6.3.

```
try {

$dns = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oophp");
$sql = 'Select name,meaning,gender FROM names ORDER BY name';

$result  = $dns->query($sql);


} catch(exception $e) {
$error = $e->getMessage();

}

if (isset($error)) {

echo $error;

}else {

echo 'Connection succesful<br/>';
}

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Mention user-name and password for DB-connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dns = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oophp");
```

This won't work: you did not provide an user account (and password).
So $dns won't contain a PDO object.

You need to provide a proper connection string. Then it'll work probably.

The line for this is:

```
$dns = new PDO(dsn, username, password);
```

Comment: yh, but i don't use a password for my xampp server

Comment: Then provide an empty string. You still need the username. Probably root?

Comment: the second script still says "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\pdo_oop\pdo_fetch.php on line 52"

Comment: That means that query() did not return an object, but "false". Your query is not correct in that case.